# AWS Install SSL from Certificate Manager (Free from AWS) to ELB and apply to EC2 Windows Platform IIS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, iis

Greeting

I have created the Certificate through Certificate Manager in AWS, the free one. And successfully verified as well as put it in the Elastic Load Balancer (ELB). The status of the certificate shows it's issued and Is Used? shows Yes in the Certificate Manager.

Overall, I have completed these two steps without any problem, but the SSL does not work with my domain name. When I type "mydomain.com" with or without prefix http://, it works, but when I type "mydomain.com" with https:// prefix, it does not work

I have researched to find the solution and a way to install SSL into Microsoft Windows IIS on AWS, but no document describes about that.

Can anyone share this experience? I really appreciate

Looking forward for the reply and thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to setup SSL on your web server when you use a load balancer. Assign the SSL certificate to the load balancer (as you did). Then in your HTTPS listener in the load balancer listen on HTTPS, but connect to your web server over HTTP.

In the Amazon Console for your load balancer under the "Listeners" tab, the "Load Balancer Protocol" will be HTTPS and the "Instance Protocol" will be HTTP.

This has the benefit of offloading SSL to the load balancer which decreases CPU load on your web server.

If you do want to setup SSL on your web server, then you cannot use the Amazon SSL certificate. You will need to use the standard methods and purchase a certificate from someone else.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I have done what you have mentioned already even before I post this question, but it is still not working.

I have seen the document as well as the video on YouTube, it's working for just only setting up the ELB, Elastic Load Balancer, but they are on the Apache instance only, but I don't see a document that is working on IIS at all. I feel like there must be something I missed with this environment.

The status on Certificate Manager shows that it's issued and it is being used, but it's not working on https. I really have no idea about it.